# KineticJS draw Image inside a circle

Tags: image, draw, kineticjs

I am trying to place an image inside a circle using:

```
        var gArrow2 = new Image();
        gArrow2.src = '../../Content/images/green_s.png';
        var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
            drawFunc: function(canvas) {
              var context = canvas.getContext();
              context.drawImage(gArrow2, 256, 256, 11, 23);
              context.beginPath();
              context.arc(256, 256, this.getRadius(), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
              context.lineWidth = this.getStrokeWidth();
              context.strokeStyle = this.getStroke();
              context.stroke();
            },
            x: 256,
            y: 256,
            radius: 70,
            stroke: '#00ffff',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            opacity: 0.5
        });
        layer2.add(circle2);
```

It does not work!  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give gArrow2 time to load.  You do this through gArrow2.onload.

Always put gArrow2.src **after** it's onload.

Then put any code that uses gArrow2 **inside** the onload function.

[Edit to add layer2.draw()]

I plugged your code in and got it working.

Looks like all that was needed was layer2.draw();

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Qgnkx/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.3-beta.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 600,
            height: 600
        });
        var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer2);


        var gArrow2 = new Image();
        gArrow2.onload=function(){

            var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
                drawFunc: function(canvas) {
                  var context = canvas.getContext();
                  context.drawImage(gArrow2, 256, 256, 11, 23);
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.arc(256, 256, this.getRadius(), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                  context.lineWidth = this.getStrokeWidth();
                  context.strokeStyle = this.getStroke();
                  context.stroke();
                },
                x: 256,
                y: 256,
                radius: 70,
                stroke: '#00ffff',
                strokeWidth: 4,
                opacity: 0.5
            });
            layer2.add(circle2);        
            layer2.draw();
        }
        gArrow2.src = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house1.jpg';


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once again, your help is very much appreciated.  Unfortunately it did not work, I did not even get the circle. Thanks

Comment: Mark, I used the previous drawFunc solution that you have helped me with, and also put src after onload and it works great.  Thanks for your help.